# How can I check which function will be fired after clicking a link?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am interested how the following technique is made: http://www.otherfocus.com/
When you click on a thumbnail, the website will overlay the single page with an animation.

I consulted the source, but do not quite understand what the core of these functions is. Does anyone know how to check which function is fired after clicking a thumbnail?

Comment: It's hard to say. There's a lot going on on that page. Look through all the scripts. It's probably an animation from some common library. Maybe it's modernizr?

Comment: It's a combination of `jQuery.load` (to get the contents of the linked page) and `History.pushState` to change the URL. The animations are CSS-based and fire whent some classes on the root element are changed.

Comment: why are people downvoting this? comment please ?

Answer (score -1):

You can right click on the thumbnail and check for the source (if u using chrome), in this case it is just a link - no function. for example the left upper thumbnail is a link to this path: 'http://www.otherfocus.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/thumb-800x600.jpg'

Comment: Yes it is. But there should be a function that will animate the overlay of the new page?

Comment: Events wont show up in the DOM if you do `element.addEventListener`.